# Linking 2 strings (or arrays)

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift

I'm trying to make a connection between multiple arrays. Example; (Mario bros)

```
var names = ["Mario", "Luigi"]
var colors = ["Red", "Green"]
```

Instead of making if-statements such as `if names == "Mario" && colors == "Red"` I would like to make an easier connection - just like buttons has tags I would like to make a String-tag (`"Mario".tag = 1` and `"Red".tag = 1`)

Note that I have 10 different arrays such as the above.

Comment: Can you use tuples or structs instead of using 10 different arrays?

Comment: This is a job for classes/structs. I think using a tuple here would be pretty cumbersome.

Comment: Can you use something like it? `var names = [["name": "Mario", "tag": "1"],["name": "Luigi", "tag": "2"]]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than having 10 [parallel arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array), I suggest you create a struct with 10 properties, and make an array of those structs.

Structs are a package of data that abstracts away the details of the contents, and lets you deal with the data as a whole.

I would recommend you check out the Swift Programming guide (in its entirity). It's very well written. In particular, here is the [page on Classes and Structs.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html)

In addition, if you want to compare one struct to, say, Mario (as you do in your example), you could implement a method `==` and make your struct conform to the [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Equatable_Protocol/index.html) protocol, which will allow you do something like:

```
if someCharacter == Mario {... //automatically compares all properties.
```

See [The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2) - Protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need a ModelValue

```
struct Element {
    let name: String
    let color: String
}
```

Now given

```
let names = ["Mario", "Luigi"]
let colors = ["Red", "Green"]
```

you can create a list of `Element(s)`.

```
let elements = zip(names, colors).map { Element(name: $0.0, color: $0.1) }
```

Finally your can use it

```
elements[0].name
elements[0].color
```

Comment: Good answer if he's to continue with using these Arrays. However, I think it's worth reworking what he has to use structs from the start.